# Rendering a component on specific routes - Regex path

Tags: regex, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm trying to render a component (header) only in several specific paths but not in their children, i.e `/foo` and not in `/foo/bar`.

Say I have an array of paths:

    `let paths = ['/foo', '/bar', '/baz']`

I tried to do this but it didn't work:

```
    const x = paths.map(e => `(${path}${e}/?$)`)
    <Route
      path={x.join('|')}
      component={this.makeMyComponent}
    />
```

This didn't work either:

```
    const x = paths.map(e => `(${e}/?$)`)
    <Route
      path={`${path}(/foo$|/bar$|/baz$})}
      component={this.makeMyComponent}
    />
```

But it does match in an online regex engine:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
    <Route
      render={props => paths.some(e => props.location.pathname.endsWith(e)) ? this.makeMyComponent() : null}
    />
```